# Reading through an array

Tags: bash, script

I'm trying to systematically remove profiles on some systems that were manually installed from github.

I'm going to do so with a policy from my MDM that runs a script, however, I can't get the script to read into an array properly.

So far I have:

```
profilesToRemove=$(profiles list | grep com.github.erikberglund | /usr/bin/awk '{ print $4 }') for i in ${(f)profilesToRemove}; do
    profiles remove  "$i" done
```

The problem is I continue to get a bad substitution error with ${(f) and I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Is this [tag:zsh] not bash?

Answer (score 2):

- You're not iterating through an array. `$profilesToRemove` is not an array, it's just some lines of text.
- `${(f)profilesToRemove}` is very strange. Perhaps you meant `$profilesToRemove`?
- `for` needs to begin on a new line (or `;` separated from the previous statement).

Answer (score 0):

The new line helped - I got it using

```
 profilesToRemove () {
        profiles list | grep 'com.github.erikberglund' | awk '{print $NF}'
}

for i in $(profilesToRemove); do
        profiles remove -identifier "$i"
done
```